# Matching query doesn't exist after a new object save in Django Admin and sent to Celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm saving an object in Django Admin (Django 1.8) and passing them to Celery Task. Unfortunately, I got an error [sometimes!]: "Matching query doesn't exist". I know that this is a problem with transaction, but what is the best way to solve that problem?

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(MyAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if not change:
            celery_task.delay(obj.pk)

@app.task()
def celery_task(obj_pk):
    MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj_pk)
```

The problem is that a whole view in Django Admin is in transaction.atomic() block. And sometimes celery runs faster that the end of transaction. I'm wondering what is the best way to get this around. Adding an eta while calling celery_task is some creepy idea I think (or maybe not?) - `celery_task.apply_async((obj.pk,), eta=+10 seconds)`

Comment: Maybe some interesting link in that regard: The ticket to integrate [post commit hooks](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21803) is accepted (and there is a link to a contrib package as well). Until that in my opinion the `eta` together with configuring the retry intervals don't seem so creepy an idea (but curious on other opinions on that). At least it stays simple that way. Otherwise you could also run some independent job that checks the database for new changes every X interval and trigger the task from there.

Comment: Why don't you try to call the celery task on the `post_save` signal?

Comment: @argaen `post_save` is also called in transaction block.

Answer (score 3):

If someone still looking for this one:
[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit)

```
from django.db import transaction


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if not change:
            transaction.on_commit(lambda: celery_task.delay(obj.pk))

...
@app.task()
def celery_task(obj_pk):
    MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj_pk)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `eta` is a good idea. But the probability of race condition is still there, so along with the `eta` you can [retry a task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) on a fail over:

```
@app.task(default_retry_delay=60, max_retries=3)  # retry in 1 minute with maximum 3 retries
def celery_task(obj_pk):
    try:
        MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj_pk)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist, exc:
        celery_task.retry(exc=exc)
```